# Working with large amount of mail in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

Outlook addin opens large amount (>100) of mails one by one, saves mail body and process it further.

```
foreach (MailItemContainer mc in Mails)
{
     var inspector = mc.MailItem.GetInspector;
     var document = (Document)inspector.WordEditor; 
     document.SaveAs(tempFilePath, format);

     Process(tempFilePath);

     //dispose inspector
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inspector);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(document);
     inspector = null;
     document = null;
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mc.MailItem);
     mc.MailItem = null;
}
```

However, after some processing (usually ~80 items), exceptions start to pop up.

```
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC4104005): Operation failed.
     in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_GetInspector()
```

Disposing inspector and document via Marshal.Release/FinalReleaseComObject does not help. Closing the inspector with

```
 ((_Inspector)inspector).Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
```

results in weird behaviour: starting from the second item in the list document.SaveAs saves duplicate of this item, even though document.WordOpenXML contains correct xml of the item i got inspector from.

What's the correct way to handle multiple items in outlook? Does inspector need to be disposed in some special way?

Upd2:

After releasing mail item as well, i'm getting "The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects". 
Using MailItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard) causes Outlook to crash.

Comment: BTW Why do you need to use a word editor?

Comment: Two reasons. Working with selection, and conversion into the html with proper encoding support (MailItem.SaveAs does not handle some codepages properly).

Answer (score 1):

> Disposing inspector and document via Marshal.Release/FinalReleaseComObject does not help.

I don't think so. You need to release **all** underlying COM objects instantly, not only some of them. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article.

Comment: I've tried that, only to get a bunch of other exceptions at the very same point. That's why i've asked about the way of disposing outlook inspectors, when you open hundreds of them consecutively, for each mail in the selection.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also tried nullifying+GC.Collect. Everything happens at the main vsto thread.

Comment: I don't see the complete piece of code where you do release all objects.

Comment: Gathered everything together. That's how it looks now in my code.

Comment: Where do you release a mail item object?

Comment: I forgot about the mailItem itself. After releasing/nullifying it, i still can't process a reasonable amount of items. It seems that inspectors are staying opened, and i cannot close them.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are doing in the code. But you don't release all underlying COM objects in the code instantly what causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem with the Outlook.Inspector,

The solution is: You need to call the Close method on `Outlook.Inspector`, with `OlInspectorClose.olDiscard` parameter...

I was just setting null, it didn't help.